# Is it too strong to say "the soup will wash off/ away the lipstick"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

People often use "**wash something away/off**" with strong water force. For example,

*The flood washed away the bridge*

*Wash the mud off the bikes before you put them away.*

A woman is wearing lipstick. Is it correct for her to say "I don't want to eat soup because it will wash the lipstick off/away"?

Is it too strong to say "the soup will wash off/ away the lipstick"?

Also,"**wash off**" carry a meaning of an intentional or deliberate action. The soup might wash the lipstick randomly.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2**

I think *remove* would be more appropriate than *wash*.

A search with *lipstick* and *wash* gives us titles related to how one can get rid of stains from clothes or similar.

The phrasal verb [*wash off*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wash%20off) has this definition

> to clean (something) by using water
> Wash the mud off the bikes before you put them away.

and is not suitable for the lipstick example.

We could say

> the soup will remove my lipstick

**Edit**

or even better

> the soup will ruin my lipstick

Comment: Or just "ruin" it.

Comment: Good point, @Luke Sawczak!  I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Rainwater can wash off makeup, and so can the water in a sink. Those aren't 'strong' or 'forceful', and only one is deliberate.

Comment: Thanks, @Michael Harvey.  I have removed that erroneous sentence.

Comment: Anyway, in my experience eating solid food tends to ruin lipstick, because you instinctively lick your lips while eating.